# Rails 4: jQuery does not work on Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Rails 4 (with Bootstrap 3) project on Heroku. I have added the `rails_12factor` gem, ran the `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` command and changed the following attributes to true in my `production.rb`:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

This made the project work on Heroku with all the background pictures, but I cant make the jQuery work.

I have placed all the js in a file called `welcome.js.coffee`, and it works perfect when I run the project locally. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked your application after precompiling assets on local machine in production environment?

Comment: How are you including jquery lib in your application. Are you using any kind of jquery gem?

Comment: @KalpeshFulpagare Checked it now, and it does not work in production environment locally either..? @techvineet `gem 'jquery-rails'`

Comment: I see in the console that I get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: I think either you are not including jQuery on your page or order is wrong(i.e. you are using jQuery functions first, and after that including jquery js file)

Comment: I found the problem. After I moved `//= require jquery` to the top of my require tree in application.js, it worked.